# Why slice could call into_iter directly and do not abort?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I am a Rust newbie, I tested following code and got a question. Is type of `slice` `[T]`?If so, `[T]` is unsized, but it passed when I compiled the code. Why is that?

```
#[test]
fn test_scilce(){
    let v = vec!['a', 'b', 'v'];
    let slice = (v[1..3]).into_iter();
    // let s: String = slice.collect();
    println!("{:?}", slice);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `[T]::into_iter(self)` doesn't exist, but `[T]::into_iter(&self)` does, the compiler inserts the missing reference and treats `(v[1..3]).into_iter()` as `(&v[1..3]).into_iter()`. That is in turn the same as `(&v[1..3]).iter()` and gives out references to the elements of the vector. (There is even a [clippy lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#into_iter_on_ref) warning you of using `into_iter()` on slice or other references.)

The same auto-referencing mechanism is what allows you to write `v.len()` instead of the "correct" `(&v).len()`, despite `Vec::len` taking `&self`.